# Divide a string into pairs

Tags: python, string, substring, extract, python-re

I have the following string:

```
ip = 'MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(22027, 22943, 22026, 22939, 22025, 22936, 22025, 22932, 22027, 22929, 22030, 22926)'
```

I would like to extract the values after MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY and pair them and store as list. What I tried so far?

```
op=[]
ip = 'MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(22027, 22943, 22026, 22939, 22025, 22936, 22025, 22932, 22027, 22929, 22030, 22926)'
m=re.search(r"\bMDSYS\.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY\(([^()]+)\)", ip)
if m:
        op.append("({})".format(", ".join(re.findall(r"\d+", m.group(1)))))
print(op)
```

This does not pair the numbers. It just saves as a list with parenthesis. How do I pair the values in parenthesis and save as list.

Desired output:

```
[(22027, 22943), (22026, 22939), (22025, 22936), (22025, 22932), (22027, 22929), (22030, 22926)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regular expressions.  Just chain some .split() functions and map out pairs:

```
split_string_1 = "MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY("
split_string_2 = ")"

data = list(map(int, ip.split(split_string_1)[1].split(split_string_2)[0].split(", ")))

result = list(zip(data[:-1], data[1:]))
```

result:

```
[(22027, 22943),
 (22943, 22026),
 (22026, 22939),
 (22939, 22025),
 (22025, 22936),
 (22936, 22025),
 (22025, 22932),
 (22932, 22027),
 (22027, 22929),
 (22929, 22030),
 (22030, 22926)]
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how do I use it if the string contains float? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `int` to `float` in the `list(map(int` section.  Or, you can just use `float` and deal with the dangling `.0` afterwards if you just want integers.